# MySql conditional order by

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting

I have this table (simplified):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `item_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
)
```

I need to select all items from the table, ordered this way:

1. items with `price > 0.00` first, ordered by `price ASC`
2. items with `price = 0.00` last, ordered by `id`

I tried this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 1  
ORDER BY 
  CASE price WHEN !0.00 THEN price 
   ELSE id
  END 
ASC
```

And I get results like

| item_name | price |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 150,00 |
| bar | 0,00 |
| baz | 500,00 |
| hum | 0,00 |

How do I build the query to have

| item_name | price |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 150,00 |
| baz | 500,00 |
| bar | 0,00 |
| hum | 0,00 |

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This will do the trick..

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE 1  
    ORDER BY 
      CASE price WHEN 0 THEN 1
       ELSE -1
      END ASC, price asc, id asc
```

Comment: Wonderfull, thank you very much!

One question, the 1 and -1 from THEN and ELSE what do they mean?

Comment: It means when price is 0, assign 1 for the sort, otherwise assign -1. Any two values would work, as long as the THEN value is greater than the ELSE value.

Comment: What @Matthew mentioned. We give a value to each row (*of 1 or -1*) according to its price (0 or greater) and then sort by that value. So the rows with -1 will be first (*those with a price >0*) and those with 1 will be last (*those with price = 0*).

Answer (score 26):

You can also use the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 1  
ORDER BY price=0, price, id;
```

The part 'price=0' will be 1 for items with zero price, 0 for items with non-zero price. As the default sort order is ASC, non-zero items are now placed first.

The next bit of the order-by clause means that non-zero items are then sorted by price (again ascending). If any items with non-zero price have the same price, they will be further sorted by id, but we don't care about that.

The last part is only there for items where price=0. As all these items do have the same price, the effect is to sort all the zero-priced items by id.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ORDER BY CASE price WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END`
2. `ORDER BY IF (price=0, 1, -1)`
3. `ORDER BY price=0`