# MYSQL conditional ORDER BY statement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to have a conditional `ORDER BY` statement. In layman's terms it would be like this:

```
IF index_order IS NULL ORDER BY id ASC ELSE ORDER BY index_order ASC.
```

So basically, it'll start by ordering by the ID for all rows with a NULL index_order value, then it'll order the rest by index_order.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql conditional order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258376/mysql-conditional-order-by)

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but Bill's answer is better than that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
ORDER BY index_order, id
```

Because NULL always sorts lower than any other value. So all your rows where index_order is NULL will be grouped first. Then their order will be resolved by `id`.

---

Re your comment:

I tried it out.

```
mysql> create table foo (id int auto_increment primary key, index_order int);
mysql> insert into foo values (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, null), (4, null);
mysql> select * from foo order by index_order, id;
+----+-------------+
| id | index_order |
+----+-------------+
|  3 |        NULL |
|  4 |        NULL |
|  2 |           1 |
|  1 |           2 |
+----+-------------+
```

It orders where `index_order` is null first, and resolves the tie with `id` sorted ascending. Then it orders by non-null `index_order` ascending.

I'm not sure I understand from your description how you would want it sorted differently.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I tried that at first and it kind of works for me, however, I need the NULL rows to be ordered by ID ASC and it seems to order them by ID DESC before moving on to index_order. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess I need to specify that NULL index_order rows are to be ordered by the ID column in ascending order - them move onto index_order. As you have it above, it works except that the ordering done on the NULL rows is the reverse of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

yo can use COALESCE and NULLIF :

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(id, ''), index_order), index_order
```

to more info click [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)