# Multiple ordering on same column with different condition

Tags: mysql

I wand to order my column with different order on the behalf of other column condition.

There's a table that looks like this:

```
ID    Date         Status
--------------------------
1  - 16-JUL-2015  - 1
2  - 15-JUL-2015  - 1
3  - 11-JUL-2015  - 0
4  - 12-JUL-2015  - 0
```

if status is 1 then sort by Date ASC and is status is 0 sort by date DESC

Looking for following result

```
15-JUL-2015
16-JUL-2015
12-JUL-2015
11-JUL-2015
```

Any way to order this.  Can't find anywhere

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql conditional order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258376/mysql-conditional-order-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY Status DESC,
         CASE 
            WHEN Status = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(Date, '1900-01-01')
            ELSE DATEDIFF('1900-01-01', Date) 
         END
```