# Mysql query with multiple ORDER BY clause and IF conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query based on these conditions in an orders table,

```
// This is not an actual query
SELECT *
IF (store_id = 3) THEN ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC, 
ELSEIF (STORE_ID = 7) THEN ORDER BY WEIGHT DESC
ELSEIF ORDER BY WEIGHT = DESC  
ELSEIF (EQUAL WEIGHT) ORDER BY ORDER_DATE DESC
ELSEIF (EQUAL WEIGHT AND EQUAL ORDER_DATE) ORDER BY STORE_ID DESC
ELSEIF (EQUAL WEIGHT AND EQUAL ORDER_DATE AND EQUAL STORE_ID) ORDER BY 
SHIPPING_METHOD DESC 
FROM TABLE orders WHERE carrier_name = 'XXX'
```

This is as far as what I have got,

```
//Actual query
SELECT id,store_id,weight 
FROM orders 
WHERE carrier_name = 'XXX'
ORDER BY 
IF(store_id = 3,weight,'')DESC,
IF(store_id = 3,order_date,'')DESC, 
IF(store_id = 3,store_id,'')DESC, 
IF(store_id = 3,shipping_method,'')DESC, 
IF(store_id = 7,weight,'')DESC, 
IF(store_id = 7,order_date,'')DESC, 
IF(store_id = 7,store_id,'')DESC, 
IF(store_id = 7,shipping_method,'')DESC,
IF(TRUE,weight,'')DESC,
IF(TRUE,order_date,'')DESC,
IF(TRUE,store_id,'')DESC,
IF(TRUE,shipping_method,'')DESC
```

The result obtained is

[image]

I am not sure why 53.39 and 30.35 are not sorted. What am I doing wrong?
Please suggest if there is a better way to attain this.

This is the required result,

[image]

Comment: Your implicitly casting numbers as strings (I think). Why not use 0 or -10000 instead of ''

Comment: Your second query always using descending order, regardless of the logic.  What is the point of those checks then?

Comment: Use `CASE` statements instead of If conditions. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2258402/5002793

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have to sort all store_id 3 first, then store_id 7, then all other store_id s. This is why I have inserted the conditions.

Comment: I updated my answer, yet again, to take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected output, the following query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE carrier_name = 'XXX'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN store_id = 3 THEN 0
              WHEN store_id = 7 THEN 1
              ELSE 2 END,
         store_id,
         weight DESC
```

For an explanation of the logic in the `ORDER BY` clause, the first condition puts `store_id` 3 first, followed by 7, followed by everything else.  The next conditions orders each of these three groups in ascending order by the `store_id`.  Note that for 3 and 7, this second step will be ignored, because the `store_id` value is the same for these groups (3 and 7 respectively).  Finally, the third condition is to order by the weight in descending order.

Comment: But the data-type for weight in mysql is FLOAT. Still I have to typecast it?

Comment: Your current sort order is consistent with `weight` being treated as text, not as a number.

Comment: I modified the query with -> IF(store_id = 3,CAST(weight AS UNSIGNED),'')DESC, for all weight attributes in the query. Same result.

Comment: No, I want you to use my query, not yours.

Comment: But how can I add IF conditions in that query.  Also I have tried this earlier without typecasting,  
SELECT store_id,weight  
    -> FROM sales_orders WHERE store_id = 7
    -> ORDER BY weight DESC;
This works fine. I have tried UNION also, without any success.

Comment: Your current query is a mess, abandon it.  Show us the _exact_ output you expect.  This should make it obvious what sorting conditions you want.

Comment: Yes, I sort of feel the query is a mess, not an expert in queries. I have edited my question to include the required result.

Comment: That worked well, thanks a lot, If I am not asking too much,  can you gave an explanation or a reference link for THEN 0, THEN 1, ELSE 2, I have searched about it but cant find any.

Comment: I understand the explanation. But still am missing out on why THEN 0, THEN 1, ELSE 2 is used. Is it the same as THEN 1, THEN 2, ELSE 3? Why is this used?

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY 
  weight DESC, -- as i can see all true in your cases
  order_date DESC,
  store_id DESC,
  shipping_method DESC
```