# how to select SQL , ownerID 7 first then all from table USER ?(with OR condition )

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

The USER table structure is

```
id owneeId  delete shop

1   12       null    1
2   13       1       0
3   12       null    1
4   7        1       1
5   7        null    1
6   13       null    1
7   16       null    1
8   17       null    1
```

**Now I am getting the result of ( query given below )**

```
select * from users WHERE ownerId in ('12', '13') and delete is null  or    
ownerId not IN ('12','13')  and shop=1 and delete is null
```

I will get all users with owner id 12 or 13 (with delete null) + all users with owner id not 12 or 13 + shop =1 and dlete is null.

**Desired result**

I will give another ownerID 7.

I need to get all the users with owner id 7 first, that means; from above table ,

**all users with owner id 7 and shop =1 first ...only then all users with owner id 12 or 13 (with delete null) + all users with owner id not 12 or 13 + shop =1 and dlete is null**

query will be something like

I need to add "**select * from users where ownerId 7 first and shop 1 and delete null**" to the query(above one, this one below- both same query)

```
select * from users WHERE ownerId in ('12', '13') and delete is null  or    
    ownerId not IN ('12','13')  and shop=1 and delete is null
```

** (PS)EDIT FOR BETTER CLARITY**

My current result is

```
id owneeId  delete shop

1   12       null    1
2   12       null    1
2   7        null    1
2   13       null    1
2   16       null    1
2   17       null    1
```

what I need is- desired result

```
id owneeId  delete shop

2   7        null    1
1   12       null    1
2   12       null    1
2   13       null    1
2   16       null    1
2   17       null    1
```

all user with ownerid 7 first , then the rest...( I am getting this result as an array of objects in node , in sql as table)

PS : Owner id can be any number, in this case it is 7. It can be 912, 989,89009,...etc

Comment: I am not convinced your criteria covers all possibilities for example 7,1,null could fall into all users with owner id 7 and shop =1 first and/or all users with owner id not 12 or 13 + shop =1 and dlete is null. Please add desired result based on your sample data

Comment: Not really clear but looks like `union` is the one you are loooking for.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @P.Salmon please see my edits , I added my current result I am getting... and what I need  Is to get all users with ownerID 7 first.... then the rest. ( I need to show the owner id 7 as unlocked in front end, so that the use dont have to scroll all the way down to see the unlocked users)

Comment: @nice_dev hi mate, please see my edits, I added the result table i am getting and what i ned. I just want the ownerid 7 users to come first, the rest of the users only after getting all ownerid 7 persons.... Any help

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Oh I will definitely do that onwards, Please see my edits of current result table and the result I want. I need all users with ownerID 7 to come first...And the rest following that..

Comment: I Am not sure. If you sort by OwneeId didn't solve the problem ? If not write a case statement which will give new column as 1 for the owneeid 7 and rest of the owneeid as 2 and sort based on that column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql conditional order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258376/mysql-conditional-order-by)

Comment: Hi @Roshan , The owner Id may change, it can be 789 or 1, so I can not sort it like that. I need all the users with given owner id ( its 7 here, maybe 34, 678, etc) to come first in the resulting table, Please share any information . Thank you

Comment: `The owner Id may change` Change based on what...? You haven't explained to us what determines why `7` and not some other value should come first.  If it's some dynamic selection from a front end application, you'll have to construct your query to use that value, but the basic premise of using order by and `case` still holds.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to just combine the 2 results, you can simply use `union` like below:

```
(
    select *
    from users
    where ownerId = 7 and shop = 1
)
union
(
    select *
    from users 
    WHERE (ownerId in ('12', '13') and `delete` is null)  or    
        (ownerId not IN ('12','13')  and shop = 1 and `delete` is null)
)
```

**Note:** Using `delete` as one of the column names is not recommended since `delete` is a keyword in itself. You can rather go for `deleted_at` if it's a timestamp etc.

Comment: Have you misunderstood the request? The OP wants the results they already get, but in a particular order. The solution must hence be an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Order by won't help as he said in the comments and in his P.S

Comment: Only that this doesn't make any sense ;-) They are happy with their query except for the ordering, so all they lack is an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So, if owner_id is `912` instead of `7` in my query, how can the order by help?

Comment: It sounds like they need both a UNION and ORDER BY. Unfortunately the OP isn't clear, but the "current result" suggests they're already using a UNION, and just need to add a psuedo sort column and ORDER BY it.